# Configurar date.timezone según el pais del visitante

Tags: php, .htaccess

Quiero configurar el date.timezone según el pais del visitante. 
Porque en PHP tengo configurada una hora, para mi pais, pero esta hora claramente no es la misma para todo el mundo, esto es por el date.timezone, actualmente este es el que tengo: (En mi .htaccess)

```
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_value date.timezone "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
</IfModule>

<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_value date.timezone "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
</IfModule>
```

Ahora, para mostrar la hora hago esto:

```
    <div class="card-header"  data-timestamp="<?php echo $date[0]; ?>"align="center">
      <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i', $date[0]); ?>
    </div>
```

En mi país funciona perfectamente, pero para los visitantes de España, o Inglaterra se muestra la misma hora que Argentina.
¿Hay alguna manera de poder configurar ese `date.timezone` para que sea más automatico?

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el nombre de la zona horaria del cliente deberás hacerlo mediante `Javascript`, luego enviar esa variable mediante `HTTP (GET/POST)` o `ajax` a php y ahí asignarla para que las funciones de fechas trabajen en base a esa zona horaria.

Obtener la zona horaria con JS:

```
var resolvedOptions = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions()
console.log('Zona horaria: ', resolvedOptions.timeZone);
```

En mi caso me devolverá

```
America/Santiago
```

Luego de enviar la variable a `PHP` de la forma que más te acomode, tendrá el valor de `America/Santiago`, el cual podrás asignar en `PHP` de la siguiente forma:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

También puedes consultar la zona horaria establecida en `PHP`:

```
date_default_timezone_get();
```

Consideraciones:

> Si el modelo de negocio lo permite, será mejor trabajar siempre las fechas solo por el lado del cliente.
>
> Si necesitas almacenar fechas y mantener la zona horaria te recomiendo trabajar las fechas con timestamps

**Ejemplo practico**

Cliente (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>OBTENER HORA DESDE EL SERVIDOR</h1>
    <span>Timezone Cliente:</span>
    <strong class="clienttimezone">Cargando...</strong>
    <br/><br/>
    <span>Timezone Defecto Servidor:</span>
    <strong class="serverdefaulttimezone">Cargando...</strong>
    <br/><br/>
    <span>Hora Defecto Servidor:</span>
    <strong class="serverdefaulthour">Cargando...</strong>
    <br/><br/>
    <span>Hora con timezone cliente:</span>
    <strong class="clienttimezoneseted">Cargando...</strong>
    <br/><br/>
    <span>Hora con timezone cliente:</span>
    <strong class="clienttimezonesetedhour">Cargando...</strong>
    <br/><br/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(()=>{
            var resolvedOptions = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions() 
            $('.clienttimezone').text(resolvedOptions.timeZone)
            
            $.ajax({
                url: "gettimezone.php",
                success : (data)=> {
                    console.log(data)
                    $('.serverdefaulttimezone').text(data.timezone)
                    $('.serverdefaulthour').text(data.date)
                },
                error : ()=>{
                    alert("Error al consultar la fecha")
                }
            })

            $.ajax({
                url: "gettimezone.php?timezone=" + resolvedOptions.timeZone,
                success : (data)=> {
                    console.log(data)
                    $('.clienttimezoneseted').text(data.timezone)
                    $('.clienttimezonesetedhour').text(data.date)
                },
                error : ()=>{
                    alert("Error al consultar la fecha")
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Servidor (gettimezone.php)

```
<?php 
    function isValidTimezone($timezone) {
        return in_array($timezone, timezone_identifiers_list());
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['timezone']) && isValidTimezone($_REQUEST['timezone'])){
        date_default_timezone_set($_REQUEST['timezone']);
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8'); 
    echo json_encode(['date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()), 'timezone' => date_default_timezone_get()]);
```

Para probar el ejemplo practico crea los ficheros con los mismos nombres, ponlos dentro de tu `localhost` y listo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo, ahora lo pruebo, pero me surge una duda, la zona horaria no la configuro por el .htaccess si no el PHP?

Comment: En el .htaccess configuras la zona horaria para el servidor, la cual será utilizada por defecto en PHP. Si quieres cambiar la zona horaria en "Tiempo de ejecución" por llamarlo de alguna forma, deberá ser con la alternativa que te he mencionado en la respuesta.

Comment: Ahí lo estoy configurando, me da bien la zona horario, pero a la hora de pasarlo a PHP no me funciona:
`$zonaPHP = "<script> document.writeln(resolvedOptions.timeZone); </script>";
date_default_timezone_set($zonaPHP);`

Comment: Lo estás haciendo mal. ¿Estás creando tu vista HTML con php?

Comment: A que te refieres con crear "tu vista HTML con php"?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta añadiendo un ejemplo practico funcional, creo que será suficiente para que entiendas el funcionamiento. Saludos!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104789/discussion-between-cesar-alejandro-m-and-matist00).